# Having some Dynamic SQL issues with INT type

Tags: sql-server-2000, dynamic-sql

Hello Im using SQL2000 so I build a Dynamic Query and in the last case I have this :

```
 IF (@apepac is not null and @nompac is not null and @month is not null )
    SELECT @DynaSQL_1= @DynaSQL_1 + ' AND PACIENTE.apellidos like ''' + @apepac + '%'''+
                                    ' AND PACIENTE.nombres like ''' + @nompac + '%'''+
                                    ' AND DATENAME(MONTH,honorariotecnologo.fechaestudio) = ''' + @month +'''' +
                                    ' AND YEAR(honorariotecnologo.fechaestudio) = '+@year+''
```

so the parameter @year is declared in this way :

```
DECLARE @year int,
```

and the error I get from SQL output is :

```
Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line syntax 
43Error to convert the nvarchar value '
```

What could be wrong?

Thanks!

***By the way, Why if the parameter is declared as INT, on the body query it must have to be casted / converted? ...***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to cast or convert the INT to a NVARCHAR.  Google CAST CONVERT TSQL.

Comment: The answer that was posted later AND without a code sample! Foul, I cry! :)

Comment: both code samples are wrong, as he needed to cast to NVarchar, not varchar.  :P

And there were no answers posted when I hit "submit"  ;)

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast your @`Year` as a character value.

Try this:

```
' AND YEAR(honorariotecnologo.fechaestudio) = ' + CAST(@year AS varchar(10))
```

Answer (score 1):

You want this to take care of the conversion error...

```
' AND YEAR(honorariotecnologo.fechaestudio) = '+CAST(@year AS VARCHAR)
```

You want this if you want to add the single quote to the end of your string.

```
' AND YEAR(honorariotecnologo.fechaestudio) = '+CAST(@year AS VARCHAR) + ''''
```